# Nodemailer - SMTP Timeout - office365

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, office365, nodemailer

I am trying to use SMTP connection with nodemailer with office365 mail.

When I try to send mail, it throws up this error -

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1161:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  port: 587

It is not a proxy issue, since I tried outside of the network and it throws up the same error as well.

`

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.office365.com',
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: "xxxxx@xxx.com",
        pass: "xxxxx"
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3'
    }
});
var message = {
    from: 'Sender Name <xxx@xxx.com>',
    to: '"Receiver Name" <xxx@xxx.com>',
    subject: 'Nodemailer',
    text: 'Hello to myself!'
};
transporter.sendMail(message, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error occured');
        res.end("<html><body><h1>error</h1></body></html>");
        console.log(error);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log(response);
        res.end("<html><body><h1>success</h1></body></html>");
        console.log('Message sent successfully!');
    }
});
```

`

I tried with other services as well like Gmail, it also gives the same error inside and outside the network.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a local firewall or anti-virus product that does port blocking? My company routinely blocks computers from making outbound connections on common SMTP ports because it was a common multi-mailer virus propagation path. smtp.office365.com responds on both port 25 and 587 from a host I know to be able to initiate outbound SMTP traffic.

```
[~]# nmap -p25,587 smtp.office365.com

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-12-04 10:39 EST
Nmap scan report for smtp.office365.com (40.97.170.178)
Host is up (0.027s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
25/tcp  open  smtp
587/tcp open  submission
```

Comment: Thank you for the command. Your pointer was helpful. I used zenmap for windows to run this command.                                                                     The ports seem to be blocked. I tried enabling these ports in my local computer using Inbound rules. But still it does not work. I think they are controlled at network level.                                                                          
PORT    STATE    SERVICE     REASON
25/tcp    filtered     smtp            no-response
587/tcp  filtered     submission  no-response

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bit late but this is more for anyone else in the future.

Common cause for timeouts is you have to enable SMTP, if using a mac this can be done through [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) then look to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission). If youre on a mac, you'll have to install [WSman](https://github.com/jborean93/omi) because it doesnt come with powershell. run on port `587`. set `secure` to `false`. then make sure your config email and the email in your `auth` and `data` for `postman` are the same.